# How do you write a when clause with a comparison of several columns in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert, database-trigger

I'm making a SQLite database where I want to have three tables: Users, Books and Bought. Users exists of the columns username, password, name, street, housenumber, postcode and country, where username is the primary key. Books exists of the columns ISBN, year, title, genre, price, author, publisher, summary, numberofpages and amountinstock, where ISBN and year are the primary key. And Bought exists of the columns username, ISBN, year, amount and time, where username, ISBN and year are foreign keys.

I want to add a trigger in such a way that when there will be added a tuple to Bought the SQL will check whether there's enough of that book in stock and if so then it will change the stock number of that book in Books and add the order to Bought.

I've tried already something, but it still gives me a syntax error around the when clauses, but I do not know why.
Here is the insert trigger that I made:

```
CREATE TRIGGER BoughtInStockTrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON Bought
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.amount <= (SELECT SUM(amountinstock) FROM Books B WHERE B.ISBN = NEW.ISBN AND B.year = NEW.year))
BEGIN
    UPDATE Books
    SET amountinstock = amountinstock - NEW.amount
    WHERE ISBN = NEW.ISBN AND year = NEW.year;
END
WHEN (NEW.amount > (SELECT SUM(amountinstock) FROM Books B WHERE B.ISBN = NEW.ISBN AND B.year = NEW.year))
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Where did I make a syntax mistake?

Comment: If you check the [CREATE TRIGGER syntax](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), you'll see you can only have one `WHEN` and one `BEGIN/END` block.

Comment: How do I then make a certain if/else clause?